# Regular expression to match URL substring

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I've got what may be a trivial query but I can't seem to get my head around it.

I have some logs which I need to pull certain information from. The logs are in the format (fictional examples):

```
www.examplesite.com/user?=/exl/1241374456/in/home
www.examplesite.com/user?=/exl/1228334956/in/home
www.examplesite.com/user?=/exl/1221834456/in/home
www.examplesite.com/user?=/exl/1229934456/in/home
```

The format is always the same, i.e. `/exl/(ten digit identifier)…`.

I was wondering if it is possible to use the .NET regex match to pull this out.

I just can't seem to build a regular expression that works for this. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why regex? With the content so regular you can just use normal string find (look for `/exl/`) and then take the next 10 characters.

Comment: @user1171534 What do you need - the ten digit number or the complete URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should mark always: /exl/1241374456

```
\/exl\/\d{10}
```

Comment: Thanks, I eventually got there with it. I was over-complicating it. nice simple and elegant solution. Thanks to all who had an input!

Answer (score 0):

If you need the ten-digit identifier use this;

```
www\.examplesite\.com/user\?=/exl/(?<Number>[0-9]{10})/in/home
```

Demo [here](http://regexr.com?36e8f).

and to match the URL of the type you mentioned,use this;

```
www\.examplesite\.com/user\?=/exl/[0-9]{10}/in/home
```

Demo [here](http://regexr.com?36e8i).

or to keep it simple use this(but please note this ain't going to distinguish between a URL and a simple ten-digit number anywhere in the text)

```
[\d]{10}
```

Demo [here](http://regexr.com?36e8l).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it’s going to be the only ten-digit identifier in the string, you can just use `[0-9]{10}`.